Adding user profile searchable attributes like Employee ID or Other User Specific information that can be searchable
Is there a way in M365 Admin center to add a custom field like Employee ID or Realtor ID that can be Admin managed in bulk that can be searchable using M365 search and how would one set that up?

Here is what I do to have a custom user profile property be searchable in Microsoft 365:

Create a custom property under SharePoint Online User Profiles
service
– ensure “Policy Settings” “Default Privacy Setting:” Everyone is selected
– ensure “Search Settings” “Indexed” is selected

Fill at least one user profile with data (generally it's your job to ensure this property has correct data - e.g. you'd develop a solution to synchronize AD/AAD attribute or some 3-rd party source with SPO User Profile custom property)

Configure Search Schema – map crawled property to managed property

Select Crawled Properties and ensure search picked up your custom property and crawled it – you should see your property name under Category: People.
create a new managed property

for Full-text search

select Searchable
under Advanced searchable settings – select Full-text index: PeopleIdx


for Query-based search –

select Queryable and Retrievable
map this managed property to crawled property







References:

Searchable Custom User Profile Property in Microsoft 365
Microsoft KQL

